# how could write a program to get age as an input?

Tags: python, input, exit, restart, invalid-characters

I wanna do this but i got 3 issues a s I commented:

```
age = input("How old are you ? ")
if type(age) != int: # this line does't work
    restart = input("invalid input. Do you want to restart ? [y/n]")
    if restart == "y" :
        #restart the program
    else :
        #exit the program
```

Comment: `input` returns a `str`, even if that string happens to represent a number.

Comment: so u say i shouldnt use input in the first place to get age? what should i do then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

Use a try-except block to check the conversion of the input (`str`) to `int`

```
age = input("How old are you ? ")
try:
    age = int(age)
except ValueError:
    restart = input("invalid input. Do you want to restart ? [y/n]")
    if restart == "y" :
        #restart the program
    else :
        #exit the program
```

Comment: You may want to read [What is wrong with using a bare 'except'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)

Comment: @Brian you're right, I edited the post, thanks.